# How to create a snowflake procedure that copies tables from a database to another

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, procedure

My goal is to copy tables from a database to another using snowflake procedure so I can repeat the procedure any time I want. In the first database there is the table containing all the names of the tables. When store tables in the second database, I want to add USERNAME as an argument for the procedure before schema name.
For example:

> 1st database: database.schema_name.table_name

> 2nd database: database.USERNAME_schema_name.table_name

The following code

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE COPY_TABLES_TO_SANDBOX(USERNAME VARCHAR)
    RETURNS VARCHAR
    LANGUAGE SQL
    AS
    DECLARE
      SRC_DB VARCHAR := 'FIRST_DATABASE';
      SRC_SCHEMA VARCHAR := 'SCHEMA_NAME';
      TRG_DB VARCHAR := 'SECOND_DATABASE';
      TAB_NAME VARCHAR;
      C1 CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT USERNAME || '_' || TABLE_SCHEMA || '.' || TABLE_NAME AS SCHEMA_TAB_NAME
        FROM IDENTIFIER(SRC_DB) || '.' || IDENTIFIER(SRC_SCHEMA) || '.' || 
    IDENTIFIER('TABLES')
        WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE';
    BEGIN
      FOR REC IN C1 DO
        TAB_NAME := REC.TAB_NAME;
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE ' || IDENTIFIER(TRG_DB) || '.' || 
        IDENTIFIER(TAB_NAME) || ' AS SELECT * FROM ' || IDENTIFIER(SCHEMA_TAB_NAME) || ' 
        COPY GRANTS';
      END FOR;
      RETURN 'Tables copied successfully';
    END;

CALL COPY_TABLES_TO_SANDBOX('USERNAME');
```

throws an error:

> SQL Error [1003] [42000]: SQL compilation error:
> syntax error line 12 at position 20 unexpected 'SRC_DB'.
> syntax error line 17 at position 12 unexpected 'IMMEDIATE'.
> syntax error line 17 at position 62 unexpected '('.
> syntax error line 17 at position 69 unexpected ')'.

How can I resolve the issue or what can be improved in the code? Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a reason you 'COPY' tables instead of 'CLONE'? It would be a lot faster and it will save you time, storage space plus compute credits

Comment: @demircioglu Actually there is no reason for that, that's just the only way I could've think of. Can I ask you to provide me the code for your idea?

Comment: Definitely use clone instead of CTAS.  And I think your issue is that IDENTIFIER for a database, schema, and table combination should be done as a single IDENTIFIER.  You'll want to concatenate those values into a single variable first, and then reference the whole string as a since IDENTIFIER in your SQL.

Comment: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-clone

Answer (score 0):

form the error it looks like it is in the 'SRC_DB' syntax, looks like when you use IDENTIFIER, you need to use : , like "FROM IDENTIFIER(:SRC_DB)".

The other option is to make a string of the SQL that will be executed by Execute Immediate and capture the string in a table in case of error, that way you could see if the SQL statement is correct.